# VBA remove green text: Font.ThemeColor

Tags: vba, excel

I have these worksheets where I used green text as abbreviations to request databases, the complete name are for users only. I thought it was a good idea to use a different color so these comments can be removed easily. I've managed to take a look at all used cells in my worksheets.

What I want to do now is a test on the color of the font.

```
On Error Resume Next
If cl.Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3 Then
    cl.Value = ""
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried this:

```
For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
For Each cl In WS.Range("A1:H10").Cells

    On Error GoTo Nextiteration

    If cl.Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3 Then
        cl.Value = ""
    End If

Nextiteration:

Next
Next
```

But it remove all colored cell in my range.

Can you explain me why ?
Can you show me how to select only green cells (olive green, accent 3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is due to the way you have placed your error handling code.
When `If cl.Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3 Then` throws an exception, it is ignored and  the execution continues on the next step.

> Attempting to access a theme color for an object whose color is not
>   currently themed will result in an invalid request run-time error.

Use `Err.Number` to find out if an error is thrown.

```
----Loop----

On Error Resume Next
If cl.Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3 Then
    If Err.Number = 0 Then ' will be 0 only if no error occurred in the previous step    
         cl.Value = ""
    End If
End If
Err.Clear ' Clear error state

----End Loop----
```

Comment: I still have a run-time error '5' invalid procedure call or argument on the 'if' line. I dont understand why it is not considered as an error.

Comment: @Imorin Are you running into that error despite the `On Error` line?

Comment: Yes, this is quite bothering.

Comment: @Imorin Edited answer. Can you try again?

Comment: This is working. As I understand it, when the program encounter a second error it didn't stop because the first one wasn't cleraed. Am i right ?